# Html div z-index on Leaflet map is not selectable

Tags: html, css, leaflet

[Question Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b9apw607/1/)

I have a div on my leaflet map that z-index is 1000. But I can not select the panel on map. Map is moving on panel as well.

```
.box{ 
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:rgba(255,250,245,0.8);
bottom:0;
z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest use `$(".box").trigger("click")` for any click action on the box. Dragging/touching/scrolling events are applied on the entire document, so what you want here might be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbgfpe40/2/)

On your fiddle, `#map` holds both the map and the panel, that way I don't think it is possible to not drag the map while dragging inside the panel.

I created another div to hold both map and panel separately to create the panel overlay that cannot trigger the map drag.

Comment: Does leaflet default controls use same way? Navigation, layer controls...

Comment: I never used Leaflet but I think so. You can check that trying to click and drag on some buttons, like the zoom-in and zoom-out buttons.

Comment: I checked the zoom buttons and see they are in `map div`